# Xcode 5 - .ipa not installing for project with static library Adhoc Distribution

Tags: static-libraries, xcode5, ad-hoc-distribution

I have build an app with static library. I am trying for Ad Hoc distribution.
.ipa file installs fine on iphone 5 with IOS 7 , but same .ipa file gives error installing on same IOS version on iphone 4s and ipad.

Error message is as follows:
Unable to Download App
AppName could not be installed at this time.